# TikZ-PGF: Drawing a curve inside a binary tree graph by referencing node coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-trees, draw

I've been trying to represent a rotation inside of a a TikZ layout. I've exhausted most options in terms of naming or aliasing the node, but haven't had any luck. Effectively I'm trying to ideally reference the coordinates of three nodes {A,B,C}, then draw a semi-circular path between the three starting at A and going to C. Below is my tree block with relevant packages:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\tikzset{rn/.style      =   {draw=red, circle, dashed, inner sep=2pt, minimum size = 15pt, align=center}}
\tikzset{bn/.style      =   {draw, circle, double, inner sep=2pt, minimum size = 15pt, align=center}}
\tikzset{ebn/.style     =   {draw, circle, double, inner sep=1pt, minimum size = 5pt, align=center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [binary tree layout, scale=1.25]
    \node [bn] {30}
        child{node [bn] {20}
                child{node [ebn] {}}
                child{node [ebn] {}}
            }
        child{node [rn] {40}
            child{node [bn] {38}
                child{node (a) [rn] {35}
                    child{node [thick, rn] {31}}
                    child{node [ebn] {}}}
                child{node (b) [ebn] {}}
            }
            child{node [rn] {45}
                child{node [ebn] {}}
                child{node [ebn] {}}}
    };
    \draw [->] (a.east) arc (b.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are very close, however, `arc` is not the correct command here.  You want to draw a curved path within the triangle {a,b,c} for which you should use the `controls` operation.  You are also loading all kinds of libraries, none of which is needed for the drawing.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    rn/.style  = {draw=red, circle, dashed, inner sep=2pt, minimum size = 15pt, align=center},
    bn/.style  = {draw, circle, double, inner sep=2pt, minimum size = 15pt, align=center},
    ebn/.style = {draw, circle, double, inner sep=1pt, minimum size = 5pt, align=center},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=1.25,
        level/.style={
            sibling distance=3cm/#1,
            level distance=1cm,
        },
    ]
    \node [bn] {30}
        child{node [bn] {20}
                child{node [ebn] {}}
                child{node [ebn] {}}
            }
        child{node [rn] {40}
            child{node (c) [bn] {38}
                child{node (a) [rn] {35}
                    child{node [thick, rn] {31}}
                    child{node [ebn] {}}}
                child{node (b) [ebn] {}}
            }
            child{node [rn] {45}
                child{node [ebn] {}}
                child{node [ebn] {}}}
    };
    \draw [ultra thick,red,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
        (a) .. controls ([yshift=-.2cm]c) .. (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]